# How to fix core dump error on Azure Cloud Shell?

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-shell

Whenever I start Azure Cloud shell, it crashes with below error. Any idea how to get rid of this error. Any help is appreciated.

```
Requesting a Cloud Shell.Succeeded.
Connecting terminal...

Unhandled exception. System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Management.Automation.Configuration.PowerShellConfig' threw an exception.
 ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Management.Automation.Platform' threw an exception.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: Bad message
   at System.IO.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(String fullPath)
   at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(String path)
   at System.Management.Automation.Platform.SelectProductNameForDirectory(XDG_Type dirpath) in /PowerShell/src/System.Management.Automation/CoreCLR/CorePsPlatform.cs:line 343
   at System.Management.Automation.Platform..cctor() in /PowerShell/src/System.Management.Automation/CoreCLR/CorePsPlatform.cs:line 145
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Management.Automation.Configuration.PowerShellConfig..ctor() in /PowerShell/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/PSConfiguration.cs:line 91
   at System.Management.Automation.Configuration.PowerShellConfig..cctor() in /PowerShell/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/PSConfiguration.cs:line 57
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Management.Automation.Utils.GetPolicySettingFromConfigFile[T](ConfigScope[] preferenceOrder) in /PowerShell/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/Utils.cs:line 784
   at System.Management.Automation.Utils.GetPolicySetting[T](ConfigScope[] preferenceOrder) in /PowerShell/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/Utils.cs:line 760
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.CommandLineParameterParser.GetConfigurationNameFromGroupPolicy() in /PowerShell/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost/host/msh/CommandLineParameterParser.cs:line 578
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost.ParseCommandLine(String[] args) in /PowerShell/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost/host/msh/ConsoleHost.cs:line 289
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.UnmanagedPSEntry.Start(String[] args, Int32 argc) in /PowerShell/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost/host/msh/ManagedEntrance.cs:line 82
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.ManagedPSEntry.Main(String[] args) in /PowerShell/src/powershell/Program.cs:line 71
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be something in your profile or a corrupt clouddrive image. To "factory reset" your cloudshell do the following:

- Navigate to the resource group used for the cloudshell storage
- Navigate to the storage account in this resource group
- Navigate to "File Share", you should see a a share called "cloudshellshare".
- Delete this share.
- Restart/Start cloudshell. This should give a factory fresh cloudshell.

Comment: I don't see any resource group named cloudshell when checking with portal. How do you see cloudshell RG?

Comment: Per Factory reset advise, I ran command clouddrive unmount using bash. And restarted the cloudshell. It worked